# Get the cUrl from MySql Database

Tags: android, mysql, visual-studio, rest, xamarin

i'm creating an android app right now using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2017, i want to insert some data into MySql DB, i would like to do it using REST API, but i actually don't know how to obtain the cUrl to connect the REST API with my DB, for example "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts&#8221;" this would return a Json estructure that we can use with the api, but idk how to create or obtain that cUrl for my DB

Comment: Do you want to retrieve data from a remote MySQL db?  Or send data to a remote db?  Or do you have a local MySQL db stored on the device?  Your question as written is almost incomprehensible.

Comment: It's a remote db

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop the API (back-end) to retrieve or send the information in JSON.
So with the POST or GET or other methods, you will be able to communicate with the database
See more details here
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/consuming/rest